# How are transactions hashed together to form a Merkle Root?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block, merkle-tree

In block #59,500 there are 2 transactions

Transaction 1. 6653ad77d695752cff9fe63bbb5702a53807be534c537251d53de06aac5ca093

and

Transaction 2. 72e8781092c01e9eb1c21ba33d52ad6abc42f3807601bcd8b8074d583446346e

Would you double SHA-256 transaction 1 and then double SHA-256 transaction 2 and then combine those and double SHA-256 that value to get the Merkle Root?

Comment: Do you know if the coinbase has to be hashed as well? Would you have to copy the first transaction twice because there would technically be 3 transactions to hash?

Comment: The coinbase is included in the merkle tree. You could duplicate the last tx to make an even number for the tree

Comment: And the coinbase is hashed as well then?